# Are there something that can join only list items? - Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Now I know this is very stupid question....

I am trying to make something like a programming language in a programming language (python). This is my attempt to make the command "print".

```
progress = []
command_libary = []
command_split = []
def split_command(command):
    command2 = command.split()
    for x in command2:
        command_split.extend(x)
    command_libary.extend(command)
def C05(command3):
    split_command(command3)
    if (command_split[0] == "p" and command_split[1] == "r" and command_split[2] == "i" and command_split[3] == "n" and command_split[4] == "t" and command_split[5] == "("):
        for x in range(6, len(command_split)):
            if command_split[x] == ")":
                break
            progress.extend(command_split[x])
        print (", ".join(progress))
    command_split.pop()

C05("print(something)")
```

But it give me this:

```
s, o, m, e, t, h, i, n, g,
```

Are there in python commands with I can replace join and get:

```
something
```

- I am using python 3.6.0

Comment: `"".join(progress)`.

Comment: Why are U using ", " ? just use ""

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `print(", ".join(progress))` to  `print("".join(progress))`

`join()` returns a string in which all elements of sequence have been joined by `str` separator.

Comment: oh thanks! I understand... - Now I see this is very stupid question.... xD

Answer (score 2):

If you replace this line:

```
print (", ".join(progress))
```

with

```
print ("".join(progress))
```

it'll give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand, why you have use

```
 print (", ".join(progress))
```

?

maybe you can use:

```
 print ("".join(progress))
```

for example:

```
 >>>''.join(['0','1','2'])
 '012'
```

Comment: I am using python 2 months - when I found answer for question like how to join list it always be "use ", ".join(list)".... Ok thanks now I probably understand that. - now I see my question is very stupid